# Unable to install apk with Lombok plugin

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, lombok

I have updated my apps build tools to 28.0.0. The application fails to install to device due to the following error:

`org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'`

If I remove Lombok dependecies then everything runs without any issues.

I can't seem to figure what is the problem and am not able to find info about this online. Any thoughts?

My app gradle config:'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.budgeter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
}
```

Comment: can you share the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there is an issue with 1.18.2 version.
Rolled back to version 1.16.20. This fixed the issue.